# Installing QGIS on Debian 12 (codename 'bookworm')

Tags: installation, debian

I am trying to install QGIS on Debian testing (i.e., version 12, codename 'bookworm') following the standard instructions provided on https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu.
However, I get dependencies problems with a few packages (see snapshot below).

[image: List of packages with unmet dependencies]

I tried installing QGIS with apt, apt-get and nala, but all three methods failed so far.
Did anyone manage to get around this issue?

Comment: It is great if you can include the error messages as text to your question. Then they can be found in searches etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today.

It appears QGIS only supports stable and unstable branch of Debian (ie: Bullseye and Sid) but not the testing branch. See [QGIS installers](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#repositories).

I believe you added the repository for the stable Debian branch (Bullseye) when creating the `/etc/apt/source.list.d/qgis.sources` that way:

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: bullseye
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

After updating, when you `sudo apt install qgis` you get this error because the version of qgis you're trying to install depends on packages of the stable branch while you're on testing.

A workaround is to use the unstable Debian branch by replacing `bullseye` with `sid`, this way:

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: sid
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Then `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install qgis`. I think it's the same version as the stable branch, so I'm hoping it won't be updated every day.

**EDIT (4 days later):**
QGIS is being updated from the unstable branch, for now it works, I hope in the future, there will not be any incompatibilities between unstable packages and testing packages.